# Powershell script to get certificate serial number of in-use certificates for cleaning up Microsoft Certificate Authority

Tags: powershell, client-certificates

I need to clean up my Microsoft Certificate Authority of valid but improperly created certificates for my internal web managed devices.  I want to use Powershell to query a device to find the serial number of the certificate in use. Then using the serial number of the cert assigned to the device, I can look up the host in my CA and revoke all other certs without that serial number.  I want to use a CSV file for the hosts or IPs.  I'm not too familiar with Powershell.

Comment: Care to expand on what you mean by "improperly created" and "in use", respectively?

Comment: Some earlier created certs did not have the correct subject alternative names.  So we needed to recreate them.  In use, meaning that once we recreated them with the correct information, we reinstalled them on the device, such as a vmware host.

Comment: Look at PKITools function https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PKITools/1.2/Content/Get-IssuedCertificates.ps1 

After, you can filter certificates and do what you want to do.

Comment: @filimonic - PKITools does not seem to target the device itself, only the CA.  How do I use it to find out what certs are actually active, rather than non-expired?

Comment: @svillardi, Well I misunderstood you. You want to query `device` to determine wich certificate it uses. If it's a windows machine, you can use powershell remoting to query installed cerificates. If not, you should "catch" certificates at use time (on RADIUS server, for example). For PSRemoting: `$remoteCertificates = Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | Where-Object { $_.HasPrivateKey } | Select-Object Thumbprint, SerialNumber } -ComputerName OtherComputer`

Comment: @filimonic - So to clarify, in essence are you saying that this line of code would allow me to access https://device.domain.com, click on the lock, look at all the properties of the cert and capture the serial number?  Because that is what I'm trying to do.  I want the host and the serial number of the cert, in some kind of output.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "click on lock" ? Be more specific.

Comment: If I use Chrome, for example, and go to https://stackoverflow.com, I can click on the lock to look at the certificate in my browser.  If I click on Details, I can scroll down to Serial Number and view it.  I would assume that this is a unique identifier and I could use this info (if I were to be able to pull it using your powershell script from above) to determine the only active, in-use certificate from this host/website.  Correct?  This should have nothing to do with being a Windows, Linux, VMware or some other device.